# There is no possible_keys available, but there exists keys in the where clause

Tags: mysql, explain

```
 CREATE TABLE `words_data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `words` varchar(50) default '',
  `pid` int(8) default '0',
  `baiyephp` int(11) default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `baiyephp` (`baiyephp`),
  KEY `words` (`words`),
  KEY `pid` (`pid`),
  KEY `pid_id` (`id`,`pid`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1961736 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Explain statement: `explain select id from words_data where pid=232632;`  but no `possible_keys` and no keys listed in the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explain yields in my test environment:

```
Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables
```

Which seems to indicate that there are no data in the table with pid=232632

Comment: yes,no data in the table with the pid=232632, but there are some rows  with the pid = 260009, and also no possible_keys and no keys.